# Dead girl's ghost can be heard by friend when on running track (movie)

Tags: story-identification, movie

Basically there was this girl who was hit by a car recently and killed. She "wakes up" unable to talk to anyone and she tries to talking to her friend but they cant hear her.

Then her friend starts running on a track sad about her death and they both run at the same time causing them to hear each other.

Comment: It seems to me that it contains ghosts. Does that qualify it for this site?

Comment: Agreed...missed the part about death. CV retracted. I've edited the question into better shape but more information (age of the movie, language, actress names/descriptions etc) would be helpful.

Comment: @JudithJones - Ghosts are very firmly on-topic, especially if they're a major part of the plotline

Comment: Thank you @Valorum

Answer (score 8):

Could this be *[Amazing Stories: The Heat](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9134760/?ref_=ttpl_ov)*? Not a movie, but it had pretty good production values, exec-produced by some guy called Spielberg.

> When runner Tuka is hit by a car chasing after her friend and fellow
> runner Sterling, Tuka finds herself trapped in the afterlife as a
> ghost that no one can see or hear. She soon discovers that Sterling
> can hear her - when they both run. Now Tuka has to figure out why she
> is trapped in the afterlife, and what she has to do to move on